# DynamoDB breaking code on Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I have discovered that if I run this code using DynamoDB to store data, it will crash after ~5 requests.

```
tableName = "testTable";
item = {
    "Prompt": prompt,
    "Reprompt": reprompt
};
params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Item: item
};

try {

    dynamo.putItem(params, this.emit(':askWithCard', prompt, reprompt));

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

If I run without put into DynamoDB, the code runs without breaking.
Can anyone help with a better solution here?
This is an Alexa skill, by the way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are the partition/sort keys of `testTable` covered by the keys you provide in item? That is one reason a putItem request might fail. Another reason it might fail is a lack of available provisioned throughput. Finally, you need to make sure your Lambda execution role has the IAM permissions it needs to write to DynamoDB tables.